# crash loading images in scrollview xcode

Tags: xcode, crash, imageview, scrollview

i'm making a simple Photogallery, putting around 60 images 1024x768 in the scroll view causes me a really slow execution or even a crash of the app, what am i doing wrong ?

```
-(void)sethomeview:(UIScrollView *)selscroll numimg:(int)numimg section:(NSString *)section
{   selscroll.delegate = self;
    selscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(160*numimg,80);
    sezione=section;

  for (int i=1; i<numimg+1; i++)
  {
      NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@%d.jpg",sezione,i]];        
      UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*165,0, 160, 80)];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
      [button setTitle:sezione forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(homepremuta:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      button.tag =i;
      [selscroll addSubview:button];

  }
}
```

Comment: hi are you receiving any memory warning?